# Enabling arXiv trackbacks for [other] SE communities

Tags: discussion, trackbacks

I recently became aware of [MathOverflow arXiv trackback feature](http://mathoverflow.tqft.net/discussion/278/trackbacks-to-arxiv/) that was custom implemented by @ScottMorrison. This is just awesome and certainly serves very well MathOverflow community.

I was wondering if there is a possibility of including [other] relevant SE communities to this script. In particular, [Computational Science SE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/). We are a relatively small community, but even with around 8000 questions we have [at least 255 arXiv mentions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/329095/383809).

[Our community explicitly inquired about arXiv trackbacks back in 2012.](https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/q/192/20688) Unfortunately, it seems like we [should not expect an official SE implementation of this feature any time soon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240520/383809).

For [Computational Science SE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/), this would be a good opportunity to gather the community "a bit closer" and make authors of the mentioned/discussed arXiv materials aware.

So, I am asking (I guess from Scott Morrison in particular, but not sure who is responsible for the script at the current time):

- if it is technically possible
- if additional resources are needed
- you are willing to consider it
- what additional actions are needed from Computational Science SE community

Comment: The question makes sense to me, but doesn't it belong at [CSMSE](http://cs.meta.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: @LSpice I think you meant [Computational Science Meta](https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/). My reason to place the "question" here is to get the response from MathOverflow community - who already has a wonderful tool developed by one of its members. And possibly get the attention of this particular member.  If Scott Morrison does not see this post right away, I will email him next week directly – with a formulated post on MathOverflow Meta and 10 upvotes there is a foundation for discussion.

Comment: Yes, I apologise for referring to the wrong meta.

Comment: I'm confused by the need for feedback from the MO community. What exactly are you expecting us to tell you? MO has a special clause allowing it to include a bit of homebrewed JavaScript in the code, which is why we can have trackbacks and maintain the script within the community. How would you be able to do that on a different community where this is not allowed? I don't see any reasonable way. Beg SE long enough, maybe they'll give in.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I am not aware of the technical details for this particular implementation of the feature. Hence, the very first bullet point inside my question. Begging SE is useful – and I am also doing that. Part of it is getting the evidence of the need and "universal acclaim". Hence, this discussion altogether.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I have to admit that I am not really sure about this, but I thought that the JavaScript entered into MO sites was for [citation helper](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/citation-helper/info) (before it was incorporated by SE into the editor) rather than for [arXiv trackbacks](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/trackbacks/info). Certainly there are users around here more qualified than me to say something about this - I'd hope that we'll hear from Scott Morrison at some point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The trackback mechanism is implemented "offline", and in particular does not rely in any way on our right to insert minor javascript at MO. There is a script that uses the SE API to scrape recent pages looking for arXiv identifiers, and then posts links to the arXiv. This runs on a private server. We have arranged with the arXiv folks to whitelist that server, so that it accepts the large number of trackbacks we generate.

Two solutions for CS:

1. I've just emailed Anton with a copy of our scripts; the CS folks could modify these, set up their own server, and arrange whitelisting with the arXiv.
2. Alternatively, if Anton wants to modify our script so that it scrapes both sites and send it back to me, I'm happy to continue running the expanded script on my server, avoiding the need to run two servers, and arrange separate whitelisting.

While someone is looking at the scripts, working out how to better translate LaTeX fragments in the titles might be a good idea!

Comment: Thanks a lot for getting back in such a productive way. I will take a close look at the scripts this weekend and will consult with our community.